# GridView overwrite rows

Tags: c#, gridview, datatable

I have a gridview:

```
                            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
                                ShowFooter="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%" Height="100%">
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="Nr.">
                                        <ControlStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Message">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox Native="True" ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <ControlStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Data">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtAge" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <ControlStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>
```

and 2 buttons. When I click each button, a new row is inserted in `Gridview`.
To create and bind data tot `GridView`, I have 2 functions:

```
private void AddNewRow(string s, string s1)
        {
            int rowIndex = 0;

            if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
            {

                DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
                DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
                if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        TextBox TextBoxName =
                          (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("txtName");
                        TextBoxName.Text = s;
                        TextBox TextBoxAge =
                          (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("txtAge");
                        TextBoxAge.Text = s1;

                        drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
                        drCurrentRow["RowNumber"] = i + 1;

                        dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Col1"] = TextBoxName.Text;
                        dtCurrentTable.Rows[i -1]["Col2"] = TextBoxAge.Text;

                        rowIndex++;
                    }
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
                    ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;

                    GridView1.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("ViewState is null");
            }
            SetPreviousData();
        }

        private void SetPreviousData()
        {
            int rowIndex = 0;
            if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
            {
                DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        TextBox TextBoxName = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("txtName");
                        TextBox TextBoxAge = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("txtAge");


                        TextBoxName.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Col1"].ToString();
                        TextBoxAge.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Col2"].ToString();

                        rowIndex++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

When I click on button 1, data is bound and a new row is created:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   DateTime data = DateTime.Now;
            string dt = data.ToString();
            AddNewRow("Start", dt);
         }
```

When I click on button 2, data is bound and a new row is created:

```
 protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   DateTime data = DateTime.Now;
            string dt = data.ToString();
            AddNewRow("Stop", dt);
         }
```

Let's say that first I click on button 1. Everything is ok. First row contains the message "Start" and the corresponding date. Also a new row is created. If I press button 2, row 2 contains the message "Stop" and the corresponding date, but also first row is overwritten with the message "Stop". What should I do to don't overwrite the first row?

Comment: You can add new rows to data table without using for loop. Why are you looping thru all the rows of datatable?

Comment: If for loop is required you can move `drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();` out of for loop.

Comment: If I move it out of the loop, an error is thrown. :)

Comment: What error thrown?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I have no error. But the problem is the same.